# How to parse a CSV file into an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, csv

From what i understand, This usually has to be done server side. However i have read that it is possible to point to the csv file in a .js file. This would be more useful to me as i am not messing around with server side code and stuff for this project and will be all on my local machine. I saw an article with example code to do this somewere however i can't locate that article atm. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Maybe you need: [open files locally](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access any file from the system you have to use directX in IE or read up on how to use [NPAPI](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html) for mozilla support.If you are willing to use HTML5, check out its filereader API [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/file).

Comment: I am using HTML to use the Canvas tag to draw graphs. I need to parse the csv file to get the numbers to supply to the graph.

Comment: Ideally, server side is the best option for csv parsing if you ask me.Javascript-wise these are the only available methods i am afraid.

Comment: Put the numbers in the page in a DIV or a string, or get them via AJAX parse them from there.

Comment: How would i do it server side? I have just been doing the project locally in a directory. Not been using any server code.